# Can you download a file from homepage using localhost?

Tags: html, file, download, path

I have this a tag `<a href="/assets/test.docx" download>Download</a>`. According to [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) it seems like I have setup right path to access file test.docx form CV.vue according to folder structure in the picture below. Please check and verify that I have right path.

I want to test download the file when running website in Chrome on localhost. When I click download I get error saying `Failed, no file`

What am I doing wrong?

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlU45.png)

Comment: What does your file/directory structure look like?

Comment: Please click on the link ```Folder structure``` to see project structure @painotpi

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you put slash(/) behind of your path in href, it will going to main domain of website and it doesn't matter it's localhost or real domain like example.com.

So if you find your path or file structure easily you can put that in href parameter.

For example your logo path is:

```
src/assets/logo.png
```

***Remember that you can test it by enter you path on your browser to find your correct path.**


for example:

```
localhost/src/assets/logo.png
```

OR

```
127.0.0.1:8000/src/assets/logo.png
```

If it's working correctly, you can put that on your html code like this:

```
<a href="/src/assets/logo.png" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Comment: Hi @A.Sarhangian! Thanks for your time to expain how it works. Unfortunately the link still do not work and I get the same error. And I can not get my test to work like you describe them at the bottom.

Comment: Hi @ChristianBenjaminsson, as I said, firstly you need to find your correct path instead of get that correct path from us, I mean no body can find that better than yourself.
But anyway for clarify can you firstly tell me how you have access to your logo in your app? (I want the path of your image)

Comment: Sorry @A.Sarhangian, I missed that about finding my own path. This is how my path to logo is ```<img src="@/assets/logo.png" id="logo" />```Tried that and also @/src/assets/test.docx but that does not work either

Comment: @ChristianBenjaminsson That's good, now if you open your logo image in new tab you can see where is your correct path, for example after that you may see `https://example.com/public/src/assets/logo.png` or something like that , so you can use  `/public/src/assets/test.docx` as your href parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple just remove the forward slash in front of "assets". Your code should be:

```
<a href="assets/test.docx" download>Download</a>
```

The html download attribute will add this extra slash so your code as it exists now leads to the following path.
file:///assets/0513211459.jpg.html